# Sqlalchemy print SQL query to database

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a query like this:

```
res = db.query("value").from_statement(
    text("SELECT f.val AS value "
        "FROM facts f, persons p"
        "WHERE "
        "f.person_id=:region || p.id::text")
    ).params(region="'us:'")
```

I am trying to build this SQL query:

```
SELECT f.val AS value
FROM facts f, persons p
WHERE f.person_id='us:' || p.id::text;
```

If I ran this query on `psql` it returns as expected. Now the problem I'm having here is using SqlAlchemy it returns 0 results, which makes me think perhaps the problem is in the `region` building using `::text`. I couldn't find a way to print the actual query that sqlalchemy makes to the DB.

If I do `print(str(res))` I get the what's inside `text()`. Any lights ?